# Conditional breakdpoint doesnt work in Chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I added conditional breakpoint where `event.key === "d"` but it's not touched below and I have no idea why :(
[image]

I'm using `Vite`. When I make it a normal breakpoint then it's touched but I can't press `ctrl-d` since it's touched when I press `ctrl` .

Comment: so basically you can't test it with a normal breakpoint. means it could never reach the breakpoint on key === 'd'. looks ok for me

Comment: with normal breakpoint it's not possible to reach it with ctrl-d combination since it will be touched immidiately when ctrl is pressed. But now I added condition that `event.key === "d"` and I'm wondering why it's still not touched when I'm pressing `ctrl-d` since then `event.key: "d"`.